# add space seprated data to a list read from entry box in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

reading data from entry box with stringVar

`self.temp = subs.get()`

add read data to list

`self.subjects = list(map(str, subjects.split()))`

help me out with whats wrong in the above line since data is not being added to list leaving it empty.

Comment: what is `subjects` in the second line of code? Please provide a _complete_ [mcve]. Your two disconnected lines of code don't properly illustrate the problem.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are looking for vs what you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what your problem is as you didn't provide your whole code

But, here try this if you want to split at spaces and add it to list:

```py
from tkinter import *

def _split(*args):
    global lst

    lst = var.get().split(' ')
    print(lst)


root = Tk()


lst = []

var = StringVar()
var.trace('w', _split)

entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```